# How can I find the maximum value from a multi value parameter?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I have a multi select parameter (`@month`) that lists all 12 months. The label is the abbreviation (`Jan, Feb`), the value is the integer for the month (`1, 2`).

I have another parameter (`@maxmonth`) that is internal that I want to store the maximum month that was selected in. So if the user selected January and March, `@maxmonth` would = 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. Can you provide some details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your stored procedure, you'll need to set @maxmonth to the last value of @month.  Since SQL Server treats multi-value parameters as a comma-delimited string, the following will help you to get the last value.

```
-- Check to see if only one value was selected
IF CHARINDEX(',', @month) = 0
    BEGIN 
        SET @maxmonth = @month
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @maxmonth = RIGHT(@month, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@month)) - 1)
    END
PRINT @maxmonth
```

Now, if the multi-value parameter needs to first be sorted then you'll need to do a bit more work.  See the following blog post to see how you can handle this situation: http://weblogs.asp.net/jmoon/archive/2005/04/01/396649.aspx